# HTML e-mail not displaying correctly in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook

I inherited the responsibility of fixing some legacy code that generates an HTML e-mail, so all I ask is that you go easy on me if the code looks terrible, as I didn't design it, just trying to find a fix. With the HTML code below, I expect to see this(Image is purposefully broken in this screenshot):

[image]

That's what GMail shows, and seems to be the case in most other e-mail clients... Except for Outlook 2013, which looks like this:

[image]

Most notably, the entire **BLAST DETAILS** table is missing. Putting a border on the main table tag shows this:

[image]

I've spent lots of time toying around with the troubleshooting steps suggested by [Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/16-tips-troubleshooting-html-email), and have run the code through HTML validation tools to no avail. I'm just not familiar enough with how rendering works in Outlook 2013. If someone could help solve this, or at least point me in the right direction, it would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
<img src='http://www.example.com/templates/email_header.png' alt='AX Reprographics' border='0' />
<br/>
<br/>
<table width= '500' cellpadding='2' style='font-family: arial; font-size: 12px' border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'>
            <div style='font-family: arial, sans-serif'>This message is to notify you of a pending blast. The blast was created by <strong>ReproConnect </strong>
                <br />

                <br />
                Please review the blast details below, or in your Control Center. 
                <br />

                <br />

                <strong>
                    <a href='http://www.example.com/admin/webservice.php?action=sendBlast&ID=1'>Approve and send now 
                    </a>
                </strong>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <table width= '500' cellpadding='2' style='font-family: arial; font-size: 12px'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 bgcolor='#F3F3F3' height='25'><b>&nbsp;BLAST DETAILS</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;Job</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'><b>Millington High School</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;Subject</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'><b>Invitation to Bid</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;Created</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'><b>04/23/2015 02:46:29 pm</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;# of Recipients</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'><b>1</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;Estimated Cost</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'><b>0.00</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;Attachment</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'><b></b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;Delivery Options</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'><b>Email</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign='top' width='150' height='21'>&nbsp;Content</td>
            <td valign='top'  width='350'>
                <b>Project Name: Millington High School
                    <br />
                    ________________________________________
                    <br />

                    <br /></b>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **BLAST DETAILS** table starts where a new **table row** should be.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<table width= '500' cellpadding='2' style='font-family: arial; font-size: 12px'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

I am guessing that this is what your problem is.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Thanks a ton.